# How to properly run Rust applications using the Visual Studio Code runner plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Full disclosure: complete newbie to rust and vscode here and maybe I am asking the obvious.

Problem: I have a Rust application that runs properly with vscode if I use the "run" option above the main function, but when I try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> with vscoderunner extension the console will see a ton of complaints about missing cargo crates. Example:
[image]

The way I solved it is to change the command in vscode settings file from `rustc` to `cargo run` but this feels like something that should be native. Also fiddling with the default settings file really leaves a bad taste in my mouth and I think I am missing something obvious... am I?

Comment: It should probably just be `cargo run`.

Comment: Which extension do you speak of? [This one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)?

Comment: I installed this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HarryHopkinson.vs-code-runner maybe it was a bad choice and I should use the one you linked?

Comment: actually no. I tested with a clean installation and the extension you linked produces the same results. seems like runner settings file is global to vscode and I still wonder if editing it was a good idea

Comment: I think all the information you could ever want is in the duplicate :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. It appears what I did is one of the possible listed solutions